# Slow View with hierarchy type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have hit a speed issue when using a hierarchy data type, and as I got help on StackOverflow, I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I have a table holding Locations, and it's a parent-child related table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [LocationTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GeoLocation] [geometry] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Path] [hierarchyid] NULL,
    [Level]  AS ([Path].[GetLevel]()) PERSISTED,
    [Deleted] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedUserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedUserID] [int] NULL,
    [Version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_location] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I then have a view that returns more helpful data to the developers.

```
SELECT ISNULL(l.ID,-999) AS LocationID, -- Done to allow EF to use the view. A view needs something that looks like a KEY.
        l.ParentID AS ParentID,
        LocationTypeID,
        lt.Description AS LocationType,
        l.GeoLocation,
        l.Name,
        p.Facility,
        p.Community,
        p.Unit,
        p.Pod,
        p.Cell,
        p.Bed,
        p.Zone,
        p.Building,
        p.Room
     FROM Location l
     CROSS APPLY dbo.fnPivotLocationHierarchy(l.ID) p
     INNER JOIN ref.LocationType lt
        ON lt.ID = l.LocationTypeID
```

This makes use of the following function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnPivotLocationHierarchy](@id int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    /*
        This function is used to pivot the Location table based on levels
        and paths to move to a wide view of the location data.
    */

    SELECT ID,
        [1] AS Facility,
        [2] AS Community,
        [3] AS Unit,
        [4] AS Pod,
        [5] AS Cell,
        [6] AS Bed,
        [7] AS Zone,
        [8] AS Building,
        [9] AS Room 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            p.ID, 
            l.[Name], 
            l.[Level] + CASE WHEN l.LocationTypeID IN(11,12,13) THEN 5 ELSE 0 END AS Level -- Note, 11,12 and 13 are Non-Accomodation types, so the level needs to move to the Non-Accomodation area
        FROM dbo.Location AS l
        INNER JOIN dbo.Location AS p
            ON p.[Path].IsDescendantOf(l.[Path]) = 1
        WHERE p.ID = @id
    ) AS p
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Name)
        FOR [Level] IN (
            [1],
            [2],
            [3],
            [4],
            [5],
            [6],
            [7],
            [8],
            [9]
        )
    ) AS pvt;
GO
```

I'm hoping an index might help. All I have at the moment, is the primary key, and an index on ParentID.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_location_parentid] ON [dbo].[Location]
(
    [ParentID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ID],
    [Description],
    [Name],
    [LocationTypeID],
    [Level],
    [Path]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Is there a way I can improve this performance? I tried to make the view into an Indexed View, but am unable, as there is a CROSS APPLY being used.

Edit:
It seems it might not be the view that's the issue. I have found soemthing a bit strange:

```
SELECT * FROM person per
INNER JOIN dbo.Prisoner pri
ON pri.PersonID = per.ID
INNER JOIN vwLocations v
ON v.LocationID = pri.CurrentAccommodationLocationID
```

Execution Plan:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rncglc1a05fnwfa/PlanWithoutWhereClause.sqlplan?dl=0

That query runs in 0.5 seconds. It gets all records without any filter. Note that prisoners with a row in the view will only appear (INNER join in the view), which is expected. Comes back with 770 rows, as expected.

However, when I add a WHERE clause, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM person per
INNER JOIN dbo.Prisoner pri
ON pri.PersonID = per.ID
INNER JOIN vwLocations v
ON v.LocationID = pri.CurrentAccommodationLocationID
WHERE per.IsActive = 1
```

Execution Plan:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/obo6fbmrp5o4yx4/PlanWithWhereClause.sqlplan?dl=0

Same number of rows (Because only Active people have rows in the view), but takes 4.5 seconds.

The query plan when there is NO WHERE clause:
Help - not sure how to add the execution plan. Can I upload the XML?

Comment: Have you tried an index on the Path column? Also, a query plan would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @BenThul - I've edited the question. Working out how to screen shot the execution plan on an 11" Mac.... It's too long.

Comment: If you can save it to XML and put it somewhere public, that'd be more useful than a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @BenThul - I've added both execution plans for the two queries above.

Comment: Let's chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/107805/slow-view-with-hierarchy-type?tab=general